# Difference between celery called through manage.py and celery called itself

Tags: linux, django, bash, celery, django-celery

I'm deploying a Django project on DigitalOcean and I use

`$ celery worker -A project -l info &`

and

`$ celery beat -A project -l info &`

to run the Celery and Celerybeat.

Recently, I've read that I can do `python manage.py celery worker` and the same with beat.

Is there some difference or is it the same? If there is a difference, which commands should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `manage.py` was the common way of lifting Celery when `djcelery` was needed to integrate Celery and Django, which is no longer the case. You can see that [the latest docs about integrating Celery and Django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#starting-the-worker-process) do not even mention using `manage.py`.